# How can I find index of the array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexof

I am trying to find index of an array.

This is probably easy to do, but I havn't been able to find out how.

From a website, I tried to add a `findIndex` function, but I am getting an error.
How can I find the index?

```
namespace exmple.Filters
{
    class dnm2
    {
        public static byte[] Shape(byte[] data)
        {
            byte[] shape = new byte[data.Length];
            byte count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data[i] == 0)
                {
                    shape[i] = (data[i]);

                    int index = shape.findIndex(count);
                    int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
                    int index = a.Indexof((int)3);
                    count += 1;

                }
            }

            return shape;
        }

    public static int findIndex<T>(this T[] array, T item)
    {
        EqualityComparer<T> comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (comparer.Equals(array[i], item)) 
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
 
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason that [Array.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0) would not work?

Comment: I tried to use that but ide is not seing that.Actually it is not necessary for my code but I just wondered if one day I should use it.Did I not have the true library.?@ Thomas Weller

Comment: FYI when you get "an error" then please add the exact error text to your question - that saves a whole lot of guessing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0) gives you the index of an object in an array. Just make sure you use the same data types, i.e. `byte` here.

This is the full code, tested in .NET 4.5.2

```cs
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            byte[] data = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
            Console.WriteLine(Array.IndexOf(data, (byte)2));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the problem is Visual Studio is not seing IndexOf().@Thomas Weller

Comment: Which .NET version, which Visual Studio are you using? I tried this code in .NET 4.0.30319.42000, .NET Core 3.1.22 and .NET Core 5.0.14

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.7.2 .@Thomas Weller

Comment: @stckkk: this code even works in .NET 4.5.2 Are you sure that you are using Visual Studio and not Visual Studio Code? I have also posted the full code which I used for testing.

Comment: I am sure and I looked at the properties but I really could not understand.I thought I did not use the needed library but I do not think so.Probably I am doing something wrong but I have no idea what is it.@ Thomas Weller

Comment: @stckkk: there is no library needed. Please, create a new console application from scratch, paste the code and see if it works. No library needed, no Nuget package. If this does not work, Visual Studio is broken.

Comment: I am sorry for wasting your time.I noticed that I wrote the code wrongly.I wrote IndexOf(a,byte(2)) instead of writing Array.IndexOf(a, (byte)2).I really appreciate it.@Thomas Weller

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way is to use [Array.FindIndex(array, predicate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex?view=net-6.0#system-array-findindex-1(-0()-system-predicate((-0))))

```
var zeroBasedIndex = Array.FindIndex(data, x => x == (byte)2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It worked and besides that I am still wonder about why is IndexOf() function not working and how can I make it woked because that is seems like more memorible way.So if anybody write the solution I would be appreciate it@Prasad Telkikar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do but I have fixed your code.

```cs
namespace Exmple.Filters
{
    public static class DNM
    {
        public static byte[] Shape(byte[] data)
        {
            byte[] shape = new byte[data.Length];
            byte count = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                if (data[i] == 0)
                {
                    shape[i] = (data[i]);
                    int index = shape.FindIndex1(count);
                    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
                    int index1 = Array.IndexOf(a, (int)3);
                    count += 1;

                }
            }
            return shape;
        }

        public static int FindIndex1(this byte[] array, byte item)
        {
            EqualityComparer<byte> comparer = EqualityComparer<byte>.Default;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (comparer.Equals(array[i], item))
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

there were few issues in your code

1. Naming rule violations
2. byte[] already has an FindIndex so compiler was getting confused which one to use (I just removed the generic things and changed the name)
3. array object doesn't have a IndexOf Method, Array class has a method.

Comment: I did not understand why did you make my namespace 'DNM'.I write it when I created it so I can not change it and I got much more error but I guess I could not fullfill it in the write way(I am not good at using class.but thank you for your comprehensive answer.@Manish

Comment: I just changed because these are violation of naming conventions in c# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions